# Suggestions for machine learning toolset without Matlab

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence

I am new to the field of machine learning, I am planning to use python as the programing language for implementing algorithms and Java for system architecture.

As far as I understand, machine learning is more about modeling data specific to the domain, visualize the data, and choose appropriate models & parameters. Implementing the models/algorithms is the last and relatively easy step.

Matlab seems to have everything for machine learning but it is too expensive and requires to learn a new language.

What tools other than programming language do I need in general for machine learning for enterprise projects? things like data modeling, visualization,etc

Comment: This is way too broad and probably a question against the rules of SO. No worries... Python surpassed Matlab a long long time ago for ML (in terms of power, maybe not in terms of easy of use; yes, especially because the core-algorithms of all relevant libraries are written in Fortran, C, C++; and many of these are even the same as used in Matlab). I'm not sure what you mean by system-architecture, but i'm quite confident python can replace java there too.

Comment: Hi sascha, thanks for the reminder. what i mean by system architecture is every thing other than the algorithms implementations, like data warehouse, distributed systems, micro services, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a couple of years of trial and error, I would suggest you to go directly with python, possibly with scikit-learn or tensorflow (if you want to go hardcore :).

I also tried R in the past, and while it is a very valid language it has some limitations: It is single threaded by default, and although there are solutions for that, they are non as clean as python.

Also, python seems to be THE language for machine learning, it is easy to learn, and fast (depending on the interpreter implementation of course), also there is huuuuuuge support for it, lots of tutorials, documentation and, more important, libraries are actively develop and supported.

Finally, i recommend you to consider spyder as a good IDE for data science, I also tried Rodeo, but it does not seem as mature and stable as spyder.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. what about data modeling and visualization?

Comment: and sorry for the confusion. my question was to ask tools apart from programming language, tooling to help visualizing the data,  choosing appropriate models, and testing my models.

Comment: About data modelling, again, scikit-learn will do most of it. Add numpy and pandas to it, and done. As per visualization, matplotlib does it. Also scikit-learn comes with a good set of metrics to evaluate how good your models are (precission, recall, f1...)

Comment: I agree with most things you mentioned. But the speed is not really about the interpreters. There are not many, and the fastest of these (e.g. pypy) can't even handle complex libs like scikit-learn. Good performance in python's scientific stack is solely due to wrapping/mixing C, C++ and Fortran (e.g. most of sklearn is cython-code or even C; cython-code is not really *interpreted*).